# What's the best practice for generating spark radio buttons?

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

I have a list of radio buttons, which I want to be able to both set the value of programmatically and for the user to set the value of manually.

I have a small list of data items which I want to display as options in a list of radio buttons. The objects are stored in a model object, as is the currently selected item. The currently selected item is bound to the radiobutton group. The radio buttons are generated using a spark list.

I am having a problem setting the list programatically - whenever I set the current value on the radiobutton group to the first value in the list, all of the radio buttons are cleared, where the first one should be selected. I when checking in the debugger, I found the likely reason - there are two radiobuttons in the group that point to the same value, one of which isn't showing. My best guess is that the list control has created an extra item renderer which it is holding on to in case it needs to scroll the list.

Is there a way to create radioButtons based on an ArrayCollection without using a list? Failing that, is it possible to prevent the list from generating the extra item?

Comment: @J_A_X: The code is across several classes and is overall more likely to be confusing than it is to be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I gave spark best practices the finger and used a repeater, which created the correct number of radioButtons with no extras. It may be slow, but slow iteration over a set of less than ten items is O(I don't care).

Comment: Even if you can't get DataGroup to work as J_A_X suggested, you should probably just use a line or two of AS to generate them for you rather than resorting to the buggy resource hungry repeater. There's a reason it has such a reputation. I've got a few older projects that have radiobuttons in repeaters and they work, but man are they slow to render. If I could go back, I would've just looped over the array and created the buttons. If you don't need to "bind" to your dataProvider this way is super fast and easy.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `DataGroup` with a dataProvider (an ArrayList of objects holding data) with a custom item renderer that creates the radiobutton that you need.  Add proper bindings of the data object to the radiobutton (maybe even do 2 way binding for quick saving).